# Unable to see My apps page after login to paypal account

Tags: php, android, ios, paypal

I want to create app_id for paypal integration into my android app.I have created account in paypal and login at https://developer.paypal.com/.but i am unable to see applications tab and also when i click on dashbord it is showing an error "This Web Page Not Availabe".Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

We are currently facing issues with Sandbox Environment. It is under a high priority to get it fixed, and should be resolved soon.